# How to download with GTK Webkit and WebkitWebView

Tags: c, webkit, download, signals, webkitgtk

I have a WebKitWebView. On a website there is a download requested. I don't know how to write the signal download-requested that the download starts and saves  to a given directory.
I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Anjuta. I'm programming in C.

Answer (score 2):

1. Connect the signal:

   ```
   gboolean ret = FALSE;
   g_signal_connect(webView, "download-requested", G_CALLBACK(downloadRequested), &ret);
   ```
2. Write the signal handler:

   ```
   static gboolean downloadRequested(WebKitWebView* webView, WebKitDownload *download,     gboolean *handled)
   {
       const gchar* dest = g_strdup_printf("%s", "file://xxx"); // The 'dest' path should be customized path using 'webkit_download_get_uri'
       webkit_download_set_destination_uri(download, dest);
       return TRUE;
   }
   ```

   If you want to handle the download process yourself, you should `return FALSE;` here.

Comment: it did not work. I used static gboolean downloadRequested(WebKitWebView *web_view, WebKitDownload *download, gboolean handled)
{
 
  const gchar *dest = g_strdup_printf("%s", "/home/malteuser/Downloads/test.mp3"); 
  // The 'dest' p ath should be customized path using 'webkit_download_get_uri' 
  webkit_download_set_destination_uri(download, dest); 
  return TRUE; 
}

Comment: The file isn't created. I get this error: (program:3947): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_output_stream_write_all: assertion `G_IS_OUTPUT_STREAM (stream)' failed

Comment: You should use "file:///home/malteuser/Downloads/test.mp3". Pls have a try.

Answer (score -2):

He forgot to start the download !

```
static gboolean downloadRequested(WebKitWebView* webView, WebKitDownload *download, gboolean *handled)
{
  const gchar* dest = g_strdup_printf("%s", "file:///home/administrator/Downloads/test.jpg");
  webkit_download_set_destination_uri(download, dest);
  webkit_download_start(download);  //start the download
  return TRUE;
}
```